# Not working seo url from old http to https for product name and canonical urls are still on http instead of https

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, seo

I'm having issue in applying seo friendly URL in Opencart from old http to new https.

Before we used to have good seo url like domain.com/productname but last month we purchased ssl cert for our site, now all urls is now on its https version, so those product pages have changed its format for example from http://domain.com/productname if you click the links it now messy like [https://www.domain.com/index.php?*route*=productname](https://www.domain.com/index.php?_route_=productname) in opencart.

I just want to eliminate this index.php?*route*= url parameters so that all links would become domain.com/productname. I also did try GWT to fetch to see it not a redirect URL. I also did check on the header status is 200.

Canonical urls are still in **http** not **https**, and some product links are still pointing to **http** instead of **https**.

So far I don't have any issue with page like about-us contact-us they're working fine.

Here are my .htaccess below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
#RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
#RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA] 

#This setting force logo url to it's home page
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^route=common/home$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ https://www.domain.com/? [R=301,L]

#This setting force http to https version
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep redirect rules before your routing rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#This setting force logo url to it's home page
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^route=common/home$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ https://www.domain.com/? [R=301,L,NE,NC]

#This setting force http to https version
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L,NE]

#RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
#RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Also make sure to test this in a new browser to avoid old browser caches.

Comment: Yes, its' working, however some urls seems pretty unusual like some urls are pointing to https and some are in http. Canonical url are still in http instead of https. Have you encounter this kind of problem before? I check the header status and its returning 200 and also did it on google webmaster. I might have some duplicate issue with my https and http version of my site.

Comment: `force http to https` rule should be forcing `https` to every URL.

Comment: So eventually they will all go to https from http after a month or so? I guess I'll just wait for Google to index and cache those pages in https version right?

Comment: Yes that's right, eventually old cached pages will be replaced by new ones.

Answer (score 0):

another solution is to make the ssl part of your website's conf also allow override

cd /etc/apache2/sites-available

nano yourdomain.com.conf

add the following code

```
    <Directory "/var/www/html/yourdomain.com/public_html">
       AllowOverride All
       Require all granted
   </Directory>
```

inside

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
.....

</VirtualHost>
```